# Find minimum Dic key and it's value from List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of dictionaries in following format:

```
[{'ASIN': 'B009OZUPUC', 'PRICE': 39.47}, {'ASIN': 'B009OZUPUC', 'PRICE': 39.5}, {'ASIN': 'B009OZUPUC', 'PRICE': 48.58}, {'ASIN': 'B009OZUPUC', 'PRICE': 62.57}]
```

I tried this:

`min_price = min(item['PRICE'] for item in ItemPrice)`

Doing this does return correct minimum price I want to find what Corresponding `ASIN` key had lowest price. For instance `B009OZUPUC` here.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`min` can take some keyword arguments to tell it how to compare things ... one of those is `key`, which usually suffices for simple things like this

```
import operator
min(ItemPrice,key=operator.itemgetter("PRICE"))
```

Comment: Short and Sweet. Thanks for giving glimpse of Python's beauty

Answer (score 5):

Use [`min`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#min) with its [key function](http://docs.python.org/2.7/glossary.html#key-function):

```
>>> ItemPrice = [{'ASIN': 'B009OZUPUC', 'PRICE': 39.47}, {'ASIN': 'B009OZUPUC', 'PRICE': 39.5}, {'ASIN': 'B009OZUPUC', 'PRICE': 48.58}, {'ASIN': 'B009OZUPUC', 'PRICE': 62.57}]
>>> min(ItemPrice, key=lambda x: x['PRICE'])
{'PRICE': 39.47, 'ASIN': 'B009OZUPUC'}
>>> min(ItemPrice, key=lambda x: x['PRICE'])['ASIN']
'B009OZUPUC'
>>>
```

Also, here is a reference on [lambda functions](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions).